# MM:hh:mm time with c ++

Tags: c++, time

So I haven't seen here or anywhere else a way to get only the month hours and minutes using `<ctime>` or other library.

What I can do now is just get the full current date:

```
time_t now = time(0);
cout<<ctime(&now);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by *month hours and minutes*?  Do you want the time displayed as the current month:current hour:current minute?

Comment: See the std::time_get template class.

Comment: @NathanOliver " month:current hour:current minute " - Yes

Comment: When you say "month hours and minutes" do you mean the month and the number of hours and minutes into that month?

Comment: @Galik just the current month, current hour and minutes. I plan to make an Alarm clock program so i need to get those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<ctime>` standard library like this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // get current time
    std::time_t timer = std::time(0);

    // convert to 'broken time'
    std::tm bt = *std::localtime(&timer); // not thread safe

    // extract month number from 'broken time' struct
    std::cout << "month: " << (bt.tm_mon + 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "hours: " << (bt.tm_hour) << '\n';
    std::cout << "mins : " << (bt.tm_min) << '\n';
}
```

The function [std::localtime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) returns a *pointer* to an internal *statc* structure of type [std::tm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm).

Because it returns a *pointer* to an internal struct it is best to copy it to a local version by *dereferencing* the pointer using `*`:

```
// copy what the returned pointer points to into `bt`.
std::tm bt = *std::localtime(&timer);
```

Comment: yea so this works :D. can you now explain this part `tm bt = *std::localtime(&timer);`or just gimme the link to the info

Comment: @MisterWhite I added a little explanation with links to the relevant function and struct.

Comment: eg. so by doing `*localtime(&timer)` we put in memory `Wed Dec 28 06:47:03 2011` and then `tm struct` deciphers it the way we want?

Comment: @MisterWhite No, the function `localtime()` takes the time returned by the `time()` function and breaks it into its numerical components and puts them in the `tm` struct..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ctime (C time), all C things should work.  You could use strftime

```
char timestr[32];
strftime(timestr, sizeof(timestr), "%m:%H:%M", localtime(&now));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `boost` is fine for you try this one :

```
boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()).c_str()
```

Comment: Well this is full of everything

Answer (score -1):

try

```
std::put_time("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &now);
```

Comment: i use c++, not c. and what is put_time?

Comment: Error: put_time was not declared

Comment: According to the reference you linked, your example is wrong. It needs a `std::tm` struct not a `std::time_t` and you have the parameters the wrong way round.